# как преобразовать массив?

Tags: php

Мне нужно из массива:

Array ( [Вася] => 49 [Петя] => 73)

Получить массив:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Вася [count] => 49 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Петя [count] => 73 )

Каким образом можно это осуществить?

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = ['Вася' => 49, 'Петя' => 24];
$newArray = [];

foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $newArray[] = ['name' => $key, 'count' => $val];    
}
```

---

```
$array = ['Вася' => 49, 'Петя' => 24];
$newArray = [];

$newArray = array_map(function($val, $key) {
    return ['name' => $key, 'count' => $val];
}, $array, array_keys($array));
```

Comment: Как я не додумался до этого.. Спасибо большое

Comment: Галочку слева от ответа тык))